# Qlikview - sum by month

Tags: sum, qlikview

I have next script

```
Data:
load * inline
[
Year, Item, Saldo
1.1.2008, A1, 100
7.1.2008, A1, 100
21.1.2008, A1, 100
2.2.2008, B1, 200
13.2.2008, B1, 200
1.1.2010, B1, 200
12.1.2010, C1, 300
20.1.2010, C1, 300
22.2.2010, C1, 300
];

SumData:
LOAD
sum(Saldo) as SaldoSum
 RESIDENT Data
 ;
```

An i got this:

[image]

I want sum of saldo by year and month. I want to get this:

```
  year and month    Item         Saldo
  1.2008            A1             300
  2.2008            B1             400
  1.2010            B1             200
  1.2010            C1             600
  2.2010            C1             300
```

Any idea?

How to sum Saldo by month and year in script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Option**

You don't need to do a resident load. You can leave your script like this:

```
Data:
load * inline
[
Year, Item, Saldo
1.1.2008, A1, 100
7.1.2008, A1, 100
21.1.2008, A1, 100
2.2.2008, B1, 200
13.2.2008, B1, 200
1.1.2010, B1, 200
12.1.2010, C1, 300
20.1.2010, C1, 300
22.2.2010, C1, 300
];
```

Then you can do the calculations in your table:

**I)** Go to your dimension add these two dimensions in this order:

[image]

**II)** Then sum in your expression tab:

[image]

Then it will show this table:

[image]

**2) Option**

Your script should look like this:

```
Data:
load * inline
[
Year, Item, Saldo
1.1.2008, A1, 100
7.1.2008, A1, 100
21.1.2008, A1, 100
2.2.2008, B1, 200
13.2.2008, B1, 200
1.1.2010, B1, 200
12.1.2010, C1, 300
20.1.2010, C1, 300
22.2.2010, C1, 300
];

SumData:
LOAD
MonthName(Year) as MonthYear,
Item,
sum(Saldo) as SaldoSum    
RESIDENT Data Group By MonthName(Year),Item;
Drop Table Data;
```

Then create a table with this dimensions:

[image]

and this expression:

[image]

Then your table will look like this:

[image]

Comment: But I nedd to do that in script :(

Comment: See the second option ;)